# Proof the existence of two roots in $(x-1)\ln y=\ln x$ when $y \neq e$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, solution-verification

### Problem statement

Proof that $y^x\cdot x$ and $yx^2$ for $x, y \ge 1$ have a single intersection point when $y \ge e$ or $y=1$ and at least two when $1<y<e$.

I am not sure if my reasoning has flaws, how to finish it or if there is any other more elegant/simpler way of proving it. I am studying the behavior of these two functions, i.e. when is $y^x\cdot x>yx^2$. After graphing it, I have seen that in some regimes, one is greater than the other but not after a specific point. I can prove that there is a single solution for $y=e$ but I struggle to prove the other fact.

### Attempt

$$y^x\cdot x=yx^2\ \overset{x\ge1}{\rightarrow}\ y^x=yx$$
Fixing $y$ to $k$ (for clarity of the reasoning):
$$k^x=kx\ \rightarrow x\ln k=\ln k + \ln x$$
$$(x-1)\ln k = \ln x$$
And this is not further simplificable, so we have to find where a line intersects the logarithm function.

#### Case 1: $y=e$

Observing that the derivative of $\ln x$ at $x=1$ is $(x-1)\ln y$ for $y=e$, and the fact that the derivative of a function at a point is the tangent line at that point, this is the only intersection point.

Proof: $f(x)=\ln x,\ f(1)=0 \rightarrow f'(x)=\frac{1}{x};\ f'(1)=1 \rightarrow \int f'(x)|_{x=1}\mathrm{d}x=x+c\overset{f(1)=0}{=}x-1 = (x-1)\ln e\quad \blacksquare$

#### Case 2: $y\neq e$

Here I tried to find a closed expression of the points by Taylor expansion and then find the roots via Ruffini but $f(x)=\ln x$ is not well defined at $x=1$. Another idea was to try random points below and above $x=1$ and see what approximate root I found via Newton, but neither option seemed feasible. After thinking and playing with the graph a bit more, I realized that $x=1$ is like the z-rotation axis of the line $(x-1)\ln y$ so I decided to go this way:

*Fact #1: $x=1$ is a trivial solution of $(x-1)\ln y = \ln x\quad\forall\ y\in[1,\infty)$*

Proof: $\ln x|_{x=1}\ln 1 = 0 = 0\ln y=(x-1)\ln y|_{x=1}\quad \blacksquare$.

*Fact #2: both functions are strictly monotonically increasing.... and I guess this is relevant?*

And here is pretty much where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $y >e$. Then $(x-1)\ln y-\ln x$ is an increasing function of $x$ in $[1,\infty)$ because its derivative $\ln y-\frac 1 x $ is positive for $x >1$. Since the function vanishes at $x=1$ it follows that $(x-1)\ln y-\ln x >0$ for all $ x>1$. So there is only one root in $[1,\infty)$ when $y>e$.

Suppose $y<e$. Then $\ln y-\frac 1 x >0$ if $x >\frac  1 {\ln y}$ and $\ln y-\frac 1 x <0$ if $x <\frac  1 {\ln y}$. So $(x-1)\ln y-\ln x $ is decreasing in $[1,t]$ and increasing in $[t,\infty)$ where $t=\frac  1{\ln y}$. To show that this function has two roots it is enough to show that its minimum value (attained at $x=t$ is negative. [Use IVP for this].But the  minimum value is negative because $1-t+\ln t<0$ for $t <1$. [Take $t=\ln y$ in this statement].

Comment: You are right, I corrected the statement! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks to your edit, I figured out another small correction to be done, since for $y=1$ there is as well only one single crossing point. Thank you!